# Stuck when trying to merge results of SQL queries

Tags: sql, subquery

I am stuck trying to merge the results of these two queries. An inner join resulted in my values being multiplied. I'm trying to get the results of the second table to be joined to the results of the first table. My attempts at writing a sub-query have not been successful.

Table 1 has 497 rows. Table 2 has 507 rows.

The common column between the two queries is the `[Worker]` column.

Table 1 query

```
SELECT 
    '2019-12-31' as Date, [Worker], Right([Address 3],2) as State,
    SUM([YTD Dollars]) AS Sold, SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]) AS Paid Out,
    SUM([YTD Dollars]) - SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs]) AS Ours,
    (SUM([YTD Dollars])-SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs])) * .36 AS General_Costs,
    (SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))*.16 AS MoreCosts,
    (SUM([YTD Dollars]) - SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs]))-(SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))-((SUM([YTD Dollars])-SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs])) * .360)-((SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))*.160) AS Current_Year_Profit_Out
FROM 
    [WORKER_SNAPSHOT].[dbo].[Worker-Detail-12312019]
GROUP BY 
    [Worker], [Worker Name], [Address 3]
```

Table 2 query

```
SELECT 
    '2018-12-31' as Date, [Worker], Right([Address 3],2) as State,
    SUM([YTD Dollars]) AS PrevSold, SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]) AS PrevPaid Out,
    SUM([YTD Dollars]) - SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs]) AS PrevOurs,
    (SUM([YTD Dollars])-SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs])) * .325 AS PrevGeneral_Costs,
    (SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))*.125 AS PrevMoreCosts,
    (SUM([YTD Dollars]) - SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs]))-(SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))-((SUM([YTD Dollars])-SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs])) * .325)-((SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))*.125) As PrevCurrent_Year_Profit_Out
FROM 
    [WORKER_SNAPSHOT].[dbo].[Worker-Detail-12312018]
GROUP BY 
    [Worker], [Worker Name], [Address 3]
```

Query 1 data sample

Query 2 results in similar data, simply different column names, which I would like to retain.

```
Date        Worker  State   Sold        Paid Out    Ours       General_Costs    MoreCosts   Current_Year_Profit_Loss
2019-12-31  7775    NE      124492.71   53947.32    123265.90   44375.72       8631.57        16311.28
2019-12-31  3233    NY      85287.94    19763.94    87865.97    31631.74       3162.23        33308.05
```

The desired result would be the columns from query1 being retained and the columns from Query 2 being joined to Query 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but see if it will work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
    '2019-12-31' as Date, [Worker], Right([Address 3],2) as State,
    SUM([YTD Dollars]) AS Sold, SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]) AS Paid Out,
    SUM([YTD Dollars]) - SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs]) AS Ours,
    (SUM([YTD Dollars])-SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs])) * .36 AS General_Costs,
    (SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))*.16 AS MoreCosts,
    (SUM([YTD Dollars]) - SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs]))-(SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))-((SUM([YTD Dollars])-SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs])) * .360)-((SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))*.160) AS Current_Year_Profit_Out
FROM 
    [WORKER_SNAPSHOT].[dbo].[Worker-Detail-12312019]
GROUP BY 
    [Worker], [Worker Name], [Address 3]) as table1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
    '2018-12-31' as Date, [Worker], Right([Address 3],2) as State,
    SUM([YTD Dollars]) AS PrevSold, SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]) AS PrevPaid Out,
    SUM([YTD Dollars]) - SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs]) AS PrevOurs,
    (SUM([YTD Dollars])-SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs])) * .325 AS PrevGeneral_Costs,
    (SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))*.125 AS PrevMoreCosts,
    (SUM([YTD Dollars]) - SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs]))-(SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))-((SUM([YTD Dollars])-SUM([Curr NotOurs]) + SUM([Prev NotOurs])) * .325)-((SUM([YTD Paid Out]) + SUM([YTD Cur Saving]) - SUM([YTD Prev Saving]))*.125) As PrevCurrent_Year_Profit_Out
FROM 
    [WORKER_SNAPSHOT].[dbo].[Worker-Detail-12312018]
GROUP BY 
    [Worker], [Worker Name], [Address 3]) as table2 ON table1.Worker = table2.Worker
```

Comment: I ran this as a left Join instead of an Inner Join and got what I needed.
THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!